# EXCEL Pintar uma determinada quantidade de células

Tags: microsoft-excel

tenho uma planilha que funciona como um gráfico de gantt, que vai do dia 01 ao dia 31, e minha dúvida é simples, baseado no cálculo de dia de um pedido, 12 dias por exemplo, tem como eu fazer com que o excel 'pinte' apenas 12 linhas, de 01 á 12 por exemplo?

Comment: O que você quer parece ser possível com formatação condicional, mas um exemplo mais detalhado é necessário para uma resposta exata.

Comment: Oi @Denis, obrigado pelo retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver isso será preciso criar algumas regras. Como não há referência de como fez, as regras a seguir passam a ser estas:

1) **Definir a área do Gráfico e valores de mínimo e de máximo**:

Vamos supor que a área do seu gráfico compreenda a célula **A1** (dia 1) até **A31** (dia 31), portanto cada dia do mês é representado pelo número da linha, e que também compreenda as colunas de **A** até **J**, que são 10 colunas que representam, cada uma, valores de uma faixa de 10%, totalizando 100% se consideradas todas (de **A** até **J**).

Então o valor mínimo é de **0%** e o valor máximo é de **100%**.

2) **Como tratar cada célula do gráfico em função do valor percentual do dia**:

No total, as 10 células de **A** a **J** somam **100%**, então um valor de **34%** no dia **1**, seria representado pelas células **A1**, **B1**, **C1** e  **D1** (34% está na faixa de até 40%, inclusive). Neste caso, somente estas células devem ser "pintadas".

Então a regra seria a seguinte ("valor" corresponde ao valor percentual relativo a um dia que vai de 0% a 100%):

> Valor = **0%** **=>** Nenhuma célula é pintada
>
> Valor **maior do que 0%** e **menor ou igual a 10%** **=>** A célula da coluna **A** é pintada (primeiros 10%)
>
> Valor **maior do que 10%** e **menor ou igual a 20%** **=>** A célula da coluna **B** é pintada (mais 10% considerando os primeiros 10% da coluna **A** totalizando 20%)

... e assim por diante, até:

> Valor **maior do que 90%** e **menor ou igual a 100%** **=>** A célula da coluna **J** é pintada (todas as anteriores também são pintadas neste caso, totalizando 100%)

3) **"Pintando" as células**:
Para a sua necessidade, temos três estados:

a) Sem valor (0%)

b) Com valor (até 100% inclusive) e a data do dia maior do que a do dia apontado (o dia de hoje, por exemplo)

c) Com valor (até 100% inclusive) e a data do dia menor ou igual a do dia apontado

Para tratar o gráfico serão dados valores às células conforme os três estados anteriores, respectivamente:

a) A célula ficará com o valor 0

b) A célula ficará com o valor 1

c) A célula ficará com o valor 2

Para "pintar" as células respectivamente a regra será a seguinte:

a) Branco

b) Azul

c) Laranja

Sendo que a cor laranja indica os dias já corridos incluindo o próprio dia apontado, e a cor azul indica os dias ainda não ocorridos.

4) **Fórmula para definir o gráfico e suas cores**:

Antes da fórmula, supondo que os valores percentuais de cada dia estejam nas respectivas linhas da coluna K, e que existe uma célula denominada "**Ate_este_dia**", com o valor do dia apontado; a fórmula da célula **A1** que deve ser copiada para todas as outras células que representam o gráfico, deve ser:

```
=SE(E($K1>0;$K1>=Col()*0,10);SE(A1<=Ate_Este_Dia;2;1);0)
```

Agora o gráfico já pode ser "percebido", basta verificar as regiões com valores 1 e 2, falta então "pintar"

Após copiar, você deve selecionar todas as células que pertençam ao gráfico, neste caso a faixa **A1:J31** e incluir três formatações condicionais, nas seguintes opções:

```
Formatar apenas células que contenham

    "Valor da célula"   "é igual a"     0

        Formatar: Preenchimento "Cor Branca"

        Formatar: Fonte "Cor Branca"


Formatar apenas células que contenham

    "Valor da célula"   "é igual a"     1

        Formatar: Preenchimento "Cor Azul"

        Formatar: Fonte "Cor Azul"


Formatar apenas células que contenham

    "Valor da célula"   "é igual a"     2

        Formatar: Preenchimento "Cor Laranja"

        Formatar: Fonte "Cor Laranja"
```

Pronto! o valor por dia (quando houver) será representado como um gráfico de **Gant** com "barras" de cor Laranja para os dias já corridos e azuis para os dias não corridos.